# if/else statement - moving files and continuing if file does not exist

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using python to move DBF files from one folder to multiple folders. These come to me from an S3 bucket and I unzip and move. Sometimes there will be a missing DBF. If that happens I am trying to code so that if the file is not there the script moves to the next file. I figure this would be an `if/else` statement but I am having trouble with the else part.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:\staging\DT_TABLES"

######Move Clackamas Pro41005.dbf######
in_data =  "Pro41005.dbf"
out_data = "D:/DATATRACE/OREGON/OR_TRI COUNTY/Pro41005.dbf"
data_type = ""

if in_data == "Pro41005.dbf":
        arcpy.Delete_management(out_data)
        arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)
        print 'Clackamas Moved'
else :

######Move Multnomah Pro41051.dbf######

    in_data =  "Pro41051.dbf"
    out_data = "D:/DATATRACE/OREGON/OR_TRI COUNTY/Pro41051.dbf"
    data_type = ""

    arcpy.Delete_management(out_data)

    arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)

print 'Multnomah Moved'
```

In other words, if `Pro41005.dbf` was not in the zipped file I like the script to continue to `Pro41051.dbf` This is two of eight files that I am moving. In time there will be about 20 files.

Comment: how will in_data == "Pro41005.dbf" not be true when you always set it in 3 lines above? your else will never get hit currently

Comment: Would I put a wild card? in_data = "*"

Comment: @Anthony No, you want your script to check the directory and store the name of appropriate file to `in_data` instead of you hard coding a literal. Currently `in_data` NEVER equals "Pro41051.dbf" because you didn't code it. Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IF statement right now just checked whether the variable has the same filename that you already assigned above. So it will always be true.

It seems that what you need is to check whether a file exists.

`import os
...
if os.path.isfile(in_data):`